# Entity Framework 4.3 Eager Loading Zero to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.3

I have a database that look like this:

```
[Invoice]
-PK:ID
-...

[InvoiceDetail]
-PK:ID
-FK:Invoice_ID
-...
```

I have my C# Objects that look like this:

```
[Invoice]
public virtual IEnumerable<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetails { get; set; }
...

[InvoiceDetail]
...
```

When I try to use:

```
MyDbContext.Invoices.Where(inv => inv.Id == 1).Include("InvoiceDetails").FirstOrDefault();
//or
MyDbContext.Invoices.Include("InvoiceDetails").Single(inv => inv.Id == 1);
```

I have an exception :

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'DataAccessLayer.Database.Invoice' does not declare a
>   navigation property with the name 'InvoiceDetails'.

I do not understand why it search 'DataAccessLayer.Database.Invoice' which doesn't have its model there. I also doesn't understand the "navigation property" because I am using Poco object (code first).

Any one know how I can do this zero to many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `ICollection<InvoiceDetail>` instead.

Comment: +1 Nice catch. I haven't created the class and I have not realize that the virtual method were returning an IEnumerator instead of an ICollection.